# Get vendor and device ID for keyboards

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to get the vendor ID and the device ID for all USB devices connected to my mac. can anyone point me to some resources? All I find are articles about iPhones ID which I can't adapt. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shell:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

Or, if you'd like it in XML:

```
system_profiler -xml SPUSBDataType
```

Comment: First of all thank you, it shows everything I need. The problem is that I need to intercept keys (I used Quartz events for that) and now I need to determine from which device the keystrokes are coming. Is there any way to narrow it down?

Comment: Not that I know of, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. I just don't have further guidance to offer for that.